How to provide a circle radius that represents real-world distance on an OpenLayers map?
I want to plot a circular Polygon feature that covers 200 hectares on an OpenLayers map. The projection of the map and data is set to EPSG:3857.
I believe the solution lies in this code (source), but how do I adapt it for my needs? I'm struggling to wrap my head around the math.
new ol.geom.Circle(centerLongitudeLatitude,200*1000/ol.proj.getPointResolution('EPSG:3857', 1, centerLongitudeLatitude))

And this is how I am drawing the circle:
const geometry = myFeature.getGeometry();
const circle = new Circle(geometry.getCoordinates(), myFeature.get("SIZE_HECTARES"));
myFeature.setGeometry(fromCircle(circle));


https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-geodesic.html

I've just had a look through the link but unfortunately it doesn't offer a solution I can use. The example in the link shows how you can freely draw circles on a map, and not how to draw them with a set real-world distance/size. Unless there is something else I've missed?

What about this: https://openlayers.org/en/main/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon.html#.circular
